# Receiving Error while trying to run the WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

**

### [2020-09-16 13:25:32,090] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://10.1.31.61:9711. org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://10.1.31.61:9711. at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:145) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.24.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.24.jar:?] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_261] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_261] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_261] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_261] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_261] Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Error while trying to login to data receiver :/10.1.31.61:9711 at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.login(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:50) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.24.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:139) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.24.jar:?] ... 6 more Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.exception.AuthenticationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find suitable mapped attribute for local claim http://wso2.org/claims/userid at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_261] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_261] at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_261] at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_261] at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryEventSender.processResponse(BinaryEventSender.java:163) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.24.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.login(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:44) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.24.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:139) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.24.jar:?] ... 6 more [2020-09-16 13:25:32,169] INFO - QpidServiceComponent Activating Andes Message Broker Engine... [Broker] BRK-1001 : Startup : Version: 0.11 Build: 90784:90849 [Broker] MNG-1001 : Startup [Broker] MNG-1004 : Ready : Using the platform JMX Agent [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP port 5672 [2020-09-16 13:25:32,878] INFO - listening [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP port 5672 [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP/SSL port 8672 [2020-09-16 13:25:32,924] INFO - listening [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP/SSL port 8672 [Broker] BRK-1004 : Qpid Broker Ready Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.exception.AuthenticationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find suitable mapped attribute for local claim http://wso2.org/claims/userid at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_261] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_261] at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_261] at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_261] at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryEventSender.processResponse(BinaryEventSender.java:163) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.24.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.login(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:44) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.24.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:139) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.24.jar:?]

**

Comment: are you running distributed or allinone

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following generic configs:

1. If it is distributed setup check TM is up and running
2. Check TM's port is correct and 7611 and 7711 is open
3. CHeck throttling related credentials are correct according to TM

Based on the logs, there are changes to the claim attribute mapping. Looks like claim http://wso2.org/claims/userid is mapped to non-existing attributes in the user store. Please check and set to correct available attribute,